# How to Slow down a fade-animation of jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi am setting up an animation that is supposed to make some text fade in/out by scrolling. Right now the text just disappears. How can I make this fade slower?

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() < 50) {             
        $(".centered").stop(true,true).fadeIn();
    } else {
        $(".centered").stop(true,true).fadeOut();                   
    }
});
```

Comment: I can’t see your entire code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enter the speed in ms inside the parentheses:
fadeIn(3000)

Comment: Yeah. I thought that too, but it won't work... I don't know why

Comment: Or maybe try to do it with fadeTo(speed, opacity)

Answer (score 0):

In the below code fadeIn(5000);
you can change 5000 to your required time

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() < 50) {             
        $(".centered").fadeIn(5000);
    } else {
       $(".centered").fadeOut(5000);                   
    }
 });
```

Comment: Ok so I figured it out I just have to take the ".stop(true,true)" part out. then it works with the numbers in the parentheses